# Skip content of specific element when doing findAll() in Beautifoul soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

For example: I want to find contents of element with class "author"(`soup.findall(class_='author')`) but skip searching inside elements with class "comments"((`soup.findall(class_='comments')`).

So class "author" but not inside any element with class "comments"

Is it possible to do something like this in bs?

Sample html:

```
<div class ='article'>
    <span class='author'> John doe</span> <h3>title</h3>
    (...)
    <div class='comments'>
        <div class='row'>
             <span class='author'>Whining anon</span>
             <div class='content'>
             (...)
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BS allows [`find_all` to take in a function arg as a filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function). I don't have a lot of experience with BS, but you might be able to play with this.

Comment: I'm on the trail. I need to `soup.findall(class_='author').findParents()` and check them for "comments tag". But now I'm not in shape to think about it. I will figure it out tomorrow if nobody will till then.

Comment: Add a sample of the html

Answer (score 0):

I think a way would be using a for loop and if statement to filter using .parent. This can be cleaned up for your needs but it works using item.parent['class'] to get the containing divs class for comparison.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(someHTML, 'html.parser')

results = soup.findAll(class_="author")

for item in results:
    if 'comments' in item.parent['class']:
        pass
    else:
        print item
```

Or as a comprehension:

```
clean_results = [item for item in results if 'comments' not in item.parent['class']]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work if element I want to avoid is not an immediate parent. like in `<div class='commments'><div class='row'><span class='author' >Mark</span>(...)</div></div>` Function arg as filter from R Nar comment combined with `.findParents()` seems to be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

```
def AuthorNotInComments(tag):
    c = tag.get('class')
    if not c:
        return False
    if 'author' in c:
        if tag.findParents(class_='comments'):
            return False
        return True

 soup.findAll(AuthorNotInComments)
```

or "case insensitive contains" version:

```
def AuthorNotInComments(tag):
    c=tag.get('class')
    if not c:
        return False
    p=re.compile('author', re.IGNORECASE)
    str = " ".join(c)
    if p.match(str) and not tag.findParents(class_=re.compile('comments'),
    re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    return False

soup.findAll(AuthorNotInComments)
```

I welcome any suggestions/ cleanups in code etc. It would be great if someone would figure out how to make it reusable - something like `findAll(class_="test", not_under="junk")`